# SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer throws The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key

Tags: c#, ssl, tcp, tcplistener

Cheers,

I have a *.crt with a CERTIFICATE section and a PRIVATE KEY section
I load this certificate with

```
X509Certificate2 serverCertificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile("Data\\certificate.crt");
```

Now I want to start a secure TcpListener, but get at

```
SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false);
sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate, clientCertificateRequired: true, checkCertificateRevocation: true);
```

the error "The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key"...

Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for C# .NET

For HTTPS calls, the example is provided on MSDN using TCP Listner and TCP Client.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#Anchor_5

When doing sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate, ..) you should load a PFX file along with password, instead of CER file, then it will not require registration on client machine.
if works please tell me
i have problems after this :P